# Express $y$ in terms of $x$ in logarithmic graph

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Express $y$ in terms of $x$:

I know that $y = mx + c$ translates to:

$\log y = n \log x + \log c$

All I can see in the question 2a of the graph below.

I can tell that from the graph in question 2a below that the $c$ value or $y$ intercept is $2$ and the $n$ value or gradient is $3$:

$\log_{10} y = 3\log_{10} x + \log_{10} c$

I am not sure how to progress after that.

[image]

Comment: Just to be clear, $y = mx + c$ doesn't really _translate_ to $\log y = n \log x + \log c$ (in the sense that many people might interpret the word "translate"). Rather, the equation $y = mx + c$, which would be an equation of a straight line if we plotted $x$ on one axis and $y$ on the other is _replaced_ by an equation like $\log y = n \log x + \log c$, which is an equation of a straight line when we plot $\log x$ on one axis and $\log y$ on the other.
(This may be what you meant to write; I just wanted it to be clear to
anyone else reading this.)

Comment: Actually $$ y = mx + c \rightarrow \log y = \log (mx + c)$$

Comment: @DavidK thank you for pointing that out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since for $\log_{10}{x}=0$ you have $\log_{10} {y}=2$ then using this data 
$2=0+\log_{10}{c}$ that implies $c=100$.

Now $3\log_{10}{x}+\log_{10}{c}=\log_{10}{(c \ x^3)}=\log_{10}{100x^3}$ and from 
$\log_{10}{y}=\log_{10}{(100 \ x^3)}$ passing to the exponential you obtain 
$$y=100x^3$$

Answer (score 1):

Starting with the equation at the end of the question,
$$
\log_{10} y = 3\log_{10} x + \log_{10} c, \tag1
$$
this is indeed one equation describing the function you want to find.

Notice that Equation $(1)$ implies that $\log_{10} y = \log_{10} c$
when $\log_{10} x = 0$ (which happens when $x = 1$),
and since we are given that $\log_{10} y = 2$ when $\log_{10} x = 0$,
we know that $\log_{10} c = 2$. So we can simplify Equation $(1)$ to
$$
\log_{10} y = 3\log_{10} x + 2. \tag2
$$

Next, if $A=B$ then $10^A=10^B$, so we can use Equation $(2)$ to
conclude that
$$
10^{\log_{10} y} = 10^{3\log_{10} x + 2}. \tag3
$$

The rest of the exercise is just to simplify the expressions on both
sides of Equation $(3)$, using the facts that $10^{\log_{10}a} = a$,
$10^{a+b} = 10^a 10^b$, and $10^ab = (10^a)^b = (10^b)^a$.

Answer (score 0):

$\log y = 3\log x + 2$

$$y = 10^{3\log x + 2} = 10^{3 \log x} \times 10^2 = 100x^3 $$